# Is it possible to clear a table automatically before inserting using OUTPUT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE (Id int);

DECLARE @temp TABLE (Id int);

insert into @temp
output inserted.Id into @ids 
select 10;

insert into @temp
output inserted.Id into @ids 
select 20;

insert into @temp
output inserted.Id into @ids 
select 30;

insert into @temp
output inserted.Id into @ids 
select 40;

select * from @temp
select * from @ids
```

The result is that both tables will have 4 records. I want to use the `@temp` variable to check that a record has been successfully inserted, and if not throw an error immediately after.

To avoid cluttering the code with different variables, I would like to re-use the `@temp` variable for each check.

However, with the above, records keep on getting inserted. Is there a way to clear/reset the variable automatically without using `DELETE FROM` every time before the `INSERT INTO`?

Comment: no. You have to manually delete it

Comment: Can you not use `@@ROWCOUNT` to check for success instead?

Comment: if you go through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you wouldn't find a single example or functionality that allows you to do that. I think a simple answer is a no, unless someone with really high expertise can say otherwise. I don't even see why would you need to do that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I could. would `@@ROWCOUNT` be reset for each and every insert?

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. Yep, it only gives the number of the last statement, i.e, it does reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), in general, tells you how many rows were affected by the last statement, so you can add an `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` test after each `INSERT` and that would tell you that no rows had been inserted by that statement.

The only thing to be wary of is that `@@ROWCOUNT` (like [`@@ERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)<sup>1</sup>) is reset by *practically* every statement, including things like `IF`!. So if you want more complex checks across multiple statements (or want to check both), you're better off capturing their values into local variables:

```
DECLARE @rc int
DECLARE @err int
DECLARE @ids TABLE (Id int);

DECLARE @temp TABLE (Id int);

insert into @temp
output inserted.Id into @ids 
select 10;
SELECT @rc = @@ROWCOUNT, @err = @@ERROR
--If we check @@ROWCOUNT again here, it will be equal to 1 because of the assigning SELECT
--but @rc and @err retain the values from the INSERT
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, modern code *should* be using `TRY`/`CATCH` for error handling, but I still go back to the "old school" methods at times.